# how to insert in a table like shown in this image where tusername is come from previous page

Tags: php, html, sql

i have page where i send tusername and get on 2nd page where a form is created.
i want to add multiple data in a table using that form. where id is requested and sub_code is entered by us table will save data like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf8wg.jpg

```
     <?php
      include("db.php");  
     $tusername =$_REQUEST['tusername'];



      @mysql_query("update INTO `techsub`(sub_code, tusername) 
     VALUES ('$sub_code','$tusername') where tusername='$tusername'"); 
     ?>
    <html>
     <body>
     <form method="post">
     Subject One: <input type="text" name="sub_code"><br>
     Subject Two: <input type="text" name="sub_code"><br>
     Subject Three: <input type="text" name="sub_code"><br>
     Subject Four: <input type="text" name="sub_code"><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Assign">
    </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: i'm not gonna upload it on server. this is a school project.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you out

```
<?php

include("db.php");

// Lets test if the form has been submitted

 if(isset($_POST['SubmitCheck'])) {
 // The form has been submited
     $tusername =$_REQUEST['tusername'];

foreach($_POST['sub_code'] as $sub_code) {
                        //insert your data

  @mysql_query("update INTO `techsub`(sub_code, tusername) 
 VALUES ('$sub_code','$tusername') where tusername='$tusername'"); 

 }

    }

else {
    // The form has not been posted
    }
?>
<form id="Form1" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

    Subject One: <input type="text" name="sub_code[1]"><br>
    Subject Two: <input type="text" name="sub_code[2]"><br>
    Subject Three:<input type="text" name="sub_code[3]"><br>
    Subject Four: <input type="text" name="sub_code[4]"><br>

    <input type="hidden" name="SubmitCheck" value="Assign">
    <input type="Submit" name="Form1_Submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: no luck sir,
error in line 9 " $tusername =$_REQUEST['tusername'];"
after clicking submit.
because it want tusername again after submitting.
how to send that tusername using a form submit.

Comment: @JasjeetSingh Where are you getting the value of tusername? Are you declaring any Session Variables?